# How do you make a sprite appear in pygame/python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a basic (Mario style) game but my sprite(plumber) doesn't appear, it could be hidden behind background? i'm not exactly sure, i am not getting any errors either.

```
import pygame
import sys
import itertools
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

cloud_background = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('brick_tile.png')

pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    brick_width, brick_height = brick_tile.get_width(), brick_tile.get_height()
    for x,y in itertools.product(range(0,640,brick_width),
                                 range(390,480,brick_height)):
        # print(x,y)
        screen.blit(brick_tile, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()

while running:
    setup_background()    
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

class plumber(sprite):
    def __init__(   
        self, screen, img_filename, init_position, 
        init_direction, speed):

        Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = speed

        self.base_image = pygame.image.load(Mario_sideways_sprite_2xL.png).convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.base_image


        self.pos = 50,50
```

Comment: Yes i can see the background, and the brick images. The program is running its just the plumber that's not appearing.

Comment: sorry meant the clouds. I can  not see them. I do see the bricks

Comment: yes i do see the clouds, its just the sprite(plumber) not  showing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem found is that you must modify

```
pygame.image.load(Mario_sideways_sprite_2xL.png)
```

with something like.

```
pygame.image.load("Mario_sideways_sprite_2xL.png")
```

Besides this, the code has many problems that impedes it to work. For example,

- **you do not instantiate your plumber class**.
- `class plumber(sprite)` should be `plumber(Sprite)`  (still better `Plumber(Sprite)`)

You need something like:

```
myplumber = Plumber()
allsprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((myplumber, ....))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

You could see [here](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html) the main parts of a simple program like yours.

Comment: didnt said was the only one but this indicates the code is not from cut&paste on running code, so more surprises can be expected.

Comment: I tried  your knew solution. The plumber image is still not appearing. could it be stuck behind the clouds(background image)?

Comment: @enrique2334 My solution was you to check the tutorial and try to adapt your specifications to that standard layout. There were many more problems in your code than those I indicated in my answer and I dont know how your code looks like right know. Please check tutorial, rewrite accordingly and come back with a refreshed code if still you need it.